# tablesorter uiDatepicker filter hides all rows, regardless of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'd like to use the Tablesorter `filter_formatter` "uiDatepicker" to filter results by date through selecting a range (from and to) of dates.

So far, the filter widget is rendered. Yet, when I select a date in either one or both of the inputs, all the rows of the table are hidden. How does this `uiDatepicker`-filter work?

Below I've included the html table and the tablesorter-code I use. I apply the uiDatepicker to the column-header `<th class='TransactieTijd'>`. What I think is going on, is that there is a discrepancy between the `uiDatepicker`-input (the specific date format) and the values in the cells. I've tried to implement a parser with `addParser`, and I tried to define a custom filter in `$.tablesorter.filter.types`. Neither attempts did help, so I might be doing something wrong with defining filters and/or parsers.

I'd like to get some help sorting out how to bridge the discrepancy between cell values and filter input-values, as I think there lies the problem. Am I missing something, or perhaps making a mistake?

### HTML table

```
<table class="tablesorter tablesorter-default hasFilters" id="debzoeker" role="grid">
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow" role="row" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <th tabindex="0" class="Boekdatum tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="debzoeker" style="-ms-user-select: none;" aria-label="Boekdatum: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" scope="col" data-column="0" unselectable="on">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                    <input name="Boekdatum" class="colCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" cp-click="updateCheck" data-eventid="cp-23">
                    Boekdatum
                </div>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" class="Bedrag tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted filter-parsed" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="debzoeker" style="-ms-user-select: none;" aria-label="Bedrag: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" scope="col" data-column="1" unselectable="on">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                    <input name="Bedrag" class="colCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" cp-click="updateCheck" data-eventid="cp-24">
                    Bedrag
        </div>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" class="RekeningnummerWederpartij tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="debzoeker" style="-ms-user-select: none;" aria-label="RekeningnummerWederpartij: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" scope="col" data-column="2" unselectable="on">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                    <input name="RekeningnummerWederpartij" class="colCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" cp-click="updateCheck" data-eventid="cp-25">
                    RekeningnummerWederpartij
                </div>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" class="Wederpartij tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="debzoeker" style="-ms-user-select: none;" aria-label="Wederpartij: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" scope="col" data-column="3" unselectable="on">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                    <input name="Wederpartij" class="colCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" cp-click="updateCheck" data-eventid="cp-26">
                    Wederpartij
                </div>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" class="Omschrijving tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="debzoeker" style="-ms-user-select: none;" aria-label="Omschrijving: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" scope="col" data-column="4" unselectable="on">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                    <input name="Omschrijving" class="colCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" cp-click="updateCheck" data-eventid="cp-27">
                    Omschrijving
        </div>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" class="TransactieTijd tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted filter-parsed" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="debzoeker" style="-ms-user-select: none;" aria-label="TransactieTijd: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" scope="col" data-column="5" unselectable="on">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                    <input name="TransactieTijd" class="colCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" cp-click="updateCheck" data-eventid="cp-28">
                    TransactieTijd
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow" role="row">
            <td data-column="0">
                <input class="tablesorter-filter" type="search" placeholder="" data-column="0" data-lastsearchtime="1487927054752">
            </td>
            <td data-column="1">
                <input class="filter tablesorter-filter" type="hidden" placeholder="" value="" data-column="1" data-lastsearchtime="1487927054752">
                <div class="range range1 ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
                    <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all value-popup" style="left: 0%;" data-value="<MINIMAL VALUE>"></span>
                    <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all value-popup" style="left: 100%;" data-value="<MAXIMAL VALUE>"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        <td data-column="2">
            <input class="tablesorter-filter" type="search" placeholder="" data-column="2" data-lastsearchtime="1487927054752">
        </td>
        <td data-column="3">
            <input class="tablesorter-filter" type="search" placeholder="" data-column="3" data-lastsearchtime="1487927054752">
        </td>
        <td data-column="4">
            <input class="tablesorter-filter" type="search" placeholder="" data-column="4" data-lastsearchtime="1487927054752">
        </td>
        <td data-column="5">
            <input class="dateRange tablesorter-filter" type="hidden" placeholder="" value="" data-column="5" data-lastsearchtime="1487928159675">
            <label>from</label>
            <input class="dateFrom hasDatepicker" id="dp1487927047626" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>to</label>
            <input class="dateTo hasDatepicker" id="dp1487927047627" type="text" placeholder="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="ui-sortable" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" role="row">
        <td>03-01-2017</td>
        <td>currency value</td>
        <td>account number</td>
        <td>account name</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td data-datesort="03-02-2017">03-01-2017, 00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" role="row">
        <td>07-01-2017</td>
        <td>currency value</td>
        <td>account number</td>
        <td>account name</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td data-datesort="07-02-2017">07-01-2017, 00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" role="row">
        <td>07-01-2017</td>
        <td>currency value</td>
        <td>account number</td>
        <td>account name</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td data-datesort="07-02-2017">07-01-2017, 00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" role="row">
        <td>08-01-2017</td>
        <td>currency value</td>
        <td>account number</td>
        <td>account name</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td data-datesort="08-02-2017">08-01-2017, 00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" role="row">
        <td>08-01-2017</td>
        <td>currency value</td>
        <td>account number</td>
        <td>account name</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td data-datesort="08-02-2017">08-01-2017, 00:00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

### Tablesorter Javascript

```
$("#debzoeker").tablesorter({
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
        filter_formatter : {
            '.Bedrag' : function(d,$cell, indx){
                var c = getColumnIndex(d,"Bedrag");
                return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiRange( $cell, indx, {
                    delayed : false,
                    valueToHeader : false,
                    // jQuery UI slider options
                    values : [datemin, datemax],
                    min : datemin,
                    max : datemax
                });
            }.bind(this,d),
            '.TransactieTijd' : function($cell, indx){
                return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDatepicker( $cell, indx, {
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    changeMonth : true,
                    changeYear : true
                });
            },
        }/*,
        // previously, I tried to define a filter in the headers property (see code below)
        headers: {
            ".TransactieTijd": {filter: 'datumFilter'}
        }*/
    },
}); 
$('#debzoeker > tbody').sortable();
```

### Previous attempt to implement a filter (usage commented out in the JS above)

```
$.tablesorter.filter.types.datumFilter = function( config, data ) {
    return true;
    // a test-filter.. I thought that "return true" would show all the rows anyway, but it did not have any effect (still, all rows were hidden after filling in the uiDatepicker inputs)
}
```

### Previous attempt to implement a parser

The parser is based on an attribute I added to the cells, to "bridge" the value-discrepancy between the filter-input and the cell values.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'datumParser',
    is: function(s, table, cell, $cell) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        var $cell = $(cell);
        // I could have used $(cell).data(), then we get back an object which contains both
        // data-lastname & data-date; but I wanted to make this demo a bit more straight-forward
        // and easier to understand.

        // first column (zero-based index) has lastname data attribute
        if ($cell.hasClass('TransactieTijd')) {
            // returns lastname data-attribute, or cell text (s) if it doesn't exist
            return $cell.attr('data-datesort') || s;
        }

        // return cell text, just in case
        return s;
    },
    // flag for filter widget (true = ALWAYS search parsed values; false = search cell text)
    parsed: false,
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Comment: Could you post to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), using the raw HTML without the HTML that tablesorter adds?

Comment: Do you mean the entire HTML that the browser receives in total? Or do you mean the raw HTML of the table and its relevant containers?

Comment: I got onto something myself, which is a bit hacky. It works, but it sort of bypasses the smarts of tablesorter. Therefore, I won't like to provide it as a definitive answer (a solution more true to Tablesorter might be better for solving this problem for anyone else). I'll post that workaround in the question as well for documentation.

Comment: I meant the raw HTML of the table.

Comment: Ok, cool. I will create a JSFiddle. I don't have it at hand right now, but I will get back at this in the next 24 hours. :)